# undefined error in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I get here as x undefined error. In my `tr` tag I have used this code (in `a.php`):

```
echo "<tr data-x'some php value'>";
```

In `b.php` I'm using code like this:

```
window.location = 'c.php?x=' + $(this).data('x');
```

Comment: please paste proper code

Comment: @user648276 So what's not happening here? The code you have looks ok. If your HTML document is XHTML, you should use double quotes `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: @user648276 Also, in your second line of code, you should use a period `.` instead of `+`. Unless this is javascript, and not PHP.

Comment: @matthewpavkov, why should he use `"` instead of `'`? XHTML accepts both `"` and `'`.

Comment: @matthewpavkov, and second line is javascript, not PHP.

Comment: @binaryLV You're right. I've been under the impression that `"` were expected in strict XHTML. Good to know.

Comment: @user648276 How are you passing the PHP variable to javascript?

Comment: @user , u should first see the value of `$(this).data('x');` in console/ alert

Comment: @user648276, have you set data `'x'` to `$(this)`? I.e., is there anything like `$('a.php.function').data('x', 'foo')` (if onClick trigger is set on `$('a.php.function')`)?

Comment: @user648276 I think posting your full code would be more helpful. Or at least a larger chunk of it.

Comment: And what are you expecting from `$(this).data('x')`? What should it return? Where (and how) do you set that value?

Comment: Ahh, I see.. Then either what Thai already commented (missing `=`), or you're might be using old jQuery. It's written in docs (http://api.jquery.com/data/) that `data-` is supported since 1.4.3.

Comment: In the first line - it should be `"<tr data-x='some php value'>"` instead of `"<tr data-x'some php value'>"`

Comment: In that case, I have to agree with matthewpavkov - you should give larger chunk of your code.

Comment: @user648276, either I'm blind or you haven't given enough. It works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use data(key) when you have put the information with data(key, value). Use attr(key) in this case:
"window.location = 'c.php?x=' + $(this).attr('x');"

Comment: `data(key)` can be used when HTML tag has `data-key` attribute. E.g., If you have `<img id='test' data-something='foo bar' alt='' src='image.png'/>`, you can get `foo bar` by using `$('#test').data('something')`.

Comment: Have to admit though, that `data-*` attributes seem to be HTML5-specific, and while they work with good old XHTML documents, they make XHTML code invalid.